# Using vlcj with proxy

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I have video file which is only playable using proxy in vlc player, when I try to open it with vlcj I am unable to connect to this media - I've been trying to use http proxy configuration option in mrl ( `http://path_to_media :http-proxy=proxy_address` ) - but it didn't work for me yet. I've also tried setting environment variable `http_proxy` but it also didn't work for me. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Maybe there shouldn;t be a whitespace between path to media and configuration option? Maybe config options do not work on Windows? How can I access this video (I know I could use transcoding to do it but it seems like overkill, I feel there should be a simpler way)

Comment: Please share logs and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you want to pass options such as "--http-proxy" then this is the way to do it:

```
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--http-proxy=<your settings");
```

Or:

```
String yourProxySettings = "http://whatever.com";
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--http-proxy", yourProxySettings);
```

Then use this factory instance to create your media player.

I suppose you use this mechanism rather than using media options when you invoke play() because you are configuring the VLC instance itself, not the individual media.

*Caveat: In the versions of VLC I have, I do not see the --http-proxy option reported as an available command-line option.*

Answer (score 0):

You could make the request in Java, retrieve a stream and use https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/de90d77bc288843b4d07dad84ff9d0515e906657/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/media/callback/AbstractCallbackMedia.java to give it to vlcj for playback.

Edit:

Else use

```
--http-proxy=<string>      HTTP proxy
          HTTP proxy to be used It must be of the form
          http://[user@]myproxy.mydomain:myport/ ; if empty, the http_proxy
          environment variable will be tried.
```

from https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/. First try to find the correct command with the normal VLC CLI. Share your try in full here.

Comment: the problem is I've already created my player and I'm not keen on changing the code in this moment so I'm trying alternate ways that take the responsiblity for proxying the stream to libVLC